# ElasticSearch: Is it possible to use dfs_query_then_fetch with the explain API?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Did the `Explain` endpoint ever support `search_type: dfs_query_then_fetch`? If it does now (I'm on 7.1), how do I specify it?

I was thrown for a loop when using the `Explain` API on two identical documents, but seeing different score calculations. Learning the documents lived in different shards, and that the TF/IDF inputs were calculated per-shard explained the difference. Using `dfs_query_then_fetch` on the `Search` API normalized the scores, but the ElasticSearch .net client (both LowLevel and NEST) don't appear to expose a way to specify it for calls to the `Explain` API.

I also tried to form a request manually, passing it as a querystring or request body parameter. Both fail saying the argument is invalid. I thought perhaps the `Explain` endpoint didn't offer a way to specify `dfs_query_then_fetch`, but digging through some old issues it appears that it at least did at some point:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2612

Answer (score 0):

Search type is not supported on the explain API. An approach that might work would be to use the Search API with `dfs_query_then_fetch` and `explain`, with a compound query that filters only to the document you're interested in (using [`IdsQuery`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/ids-query-usage.html)), along with the query you want the explanation for.